# ./zshrc is corrupted; crashing when opens my WSL bash

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zsh

I'm on WSL. I went to zsh from bash and based on this [advises here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743928/command-not-found-after-npm-install-in-zsh#comment89734920_40375497) I added `source ~/.bashrc` at the beginning of my `~/.zshrc` file in order to be able to use nvm, node, npm commands in zsh. But now when I open my WSL bash, i see infinite errors like below...

[image]

I tried `ctrl+c`, `exit` all don't do nothing...I need to go back to my ~/.zshrc to try other ideas..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the `ubuntu.exe` with a specific command to bypass your login shell. Something like one of these commands:

```
ubuntu.exe run bash
ubuntu.exe -c bash
ubuntu.exe -c vim .zshrc
```

Then use bash or Vim to fix your zshrc.

Sourcing `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` from `.zshrc` is ***terrible*** advice. It would be better if you copied the nodejs settings from `.bashrc` to `.zshrc`, or put them into a separate file and source that from `.bashrc` and `.zshrc`.

Comment: oh man, hell yes, you saved me. I'm grateful. Thank you!!!